# AWK- string expression

Tags: awk

I have an example of a regular expression:

```
seq 20 | awk 'NR!~/^2$|^12$|^15$/'
```

The same, but with the chain expression:

```
seq 20 | awk 'NR != "2" && NR != "12" && NR != "15"'
```

Is it possible to write shorter string expression?

```
seq 20 | awk 'NR != "2" | "12" | "15" '
```

Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not to my knowledge. And like you have hinted at, you will need to use a regular expression if you would like to perform equality testing (or inequality testing, in this case) in this way.

If you have multiple values to ignore, consider using an array in the `BEGIN` block. This will make the expression shorter (i.e. the expression is now simply: `!(NR in array)`) when `awk` iterates through each line:

```
seq 20 | awk 'BEGIN { array[2]++; array[12]++; array[15]++ } !(NR in array)'
```

Results:

```
1
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
13
14
16
17
18
19
20
```

If you there is some sort of pattern to the lines your trying to ignore, consider using a `for` loop in the `BEGIN` block:

```
seq 20 | awk 'BEGIN { for (i=1; i<=15; i++) array[i]++ } !(NR in array)'

16
17
18
19
20
```

Comment: I think OP wants all lines that line number not ending with 2, 12, 15. well , seq 20 might be bad example. try seq 200 or seq 1000. your first solution will print line 102 out right?

Comment: @Kent: I think he's just trying to find a shorter expression. I don't think he's trying to find lines not ending in 2, 12 or 15. It may be worthwhile re-reading the question :-)

Answer (score 1):

The first one is probably the shortest, it would be shorter if you left the anchors outside a group `()`:

```
seq 20 | awk 'NR !~ /^(2|12|15)$/'
```